# What is the drawback (if any) when loading pst-all?

Tags: pstricks

I am curious whether or not there is a drawback when we always load `pst-all`. Is there such a drawback or side effect?

Comment: It's like loading all libraries of TikZ. Unnecessary macro definitions, dimensions etc. that probably never used.

Comment: @percusse: It makes the EPS file size bigger?

Comment: Think of opening a `.txt` file in Word 2012, typing some more words, and closing. Now imagine you do the same via Notepad. That's an exaggerated difference though the outcome is the same.

Comment: @GarbageCollector: the file size is nowadays no more a problem ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pst-all` is not really *all*. It means more or less all *basic* packages. In general it makes no sense to use it. Especially when you are in a development phase where you often search for errors. Then it is easier to comment out single packages.